# make ussd call via facebook messenger bot platform

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-messenger, messenger, ussd

i'm new in facebook messenger platform and i'm trying to build a bot on top of messenger.

One of my bot's operation is to make the user able to check it's credit account. So i made a **call button** and i want it to make an **USSD Call** (i mean calling a number like **#144#**)

The Problem is : specials characters like **#** are removed when the call action come to my mobile phone.

My question i :is there any equivalent of the caracter **#** ?; Or is there any solution that will help me to make that possible ?

Comment: i've already tried to encode it by using **%23 144 %23** but the result is **144#**. i need the first hash key to be present

Comment: The purpose of this button is to make actual phone calls to people, not to trigger some other functionality. Documentation explicitly says, _“Phone number should be in the format `+<COUNTRY_CODE><PHONE_NUMBER>`, e.g. `+15105559999`”_, so I guess what you want is not possible using this button.

Comment: indeed @misorude, that's what i thought, but when i tried the **%23** it has come (except the first one)